# d3.js generate an area fill that represents the difference between two svg line paths

Tags: d3.js

I have two datasets that I am plotting in a D3.js parallel coordinate chart. I want to highlight the differences between the two.

In my example the two datasets share all values except for the economy attribute.
Blue is the first dataset and red is the second.

How can I generate an area fill that represents the difference between the two svg line paths, in the example provided the area between the red and the blue paths?

I am also open to other 'design' considerations.

[image]

Comment: Not really a coding question...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. May be better asked on [Graphic design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think it is very much a coding question, How, using the d3.js library can I generate an area fill that represents the difference between the two svg line paths. Only code will achieve this. But yes, I am also interested if anyone has any addition 'design' considerations.

Comment: This is not what your question says (although it does appear in the text). If this is the question that you want to ask, please edit and I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: Should I provide sample code?

Comment: That's always welcome, but in particular the title of your question currently doesn't suggest that you're looking for code.

Comment: To generate an area between the lines, you could simply take the `d` attributes of both of them and concatenate, then fill. Otherwise, you would need to use the area generator, which would require you to modify the data (in particular put the data for the lines you want to show the difference for together).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have included a sample here http://jsfiddle.net/hNgWQ/ But it is not clear to me how one would concatenate the values to achieve the fill?

Comment: Well you have only one line there, so there's nothing to concatenate :) For two lines, you would take the output of the `path` function for both.

Comment: I have updated the JSFiddle with a working example of two path's that have been concatenated: http://jsfiddle.net/WHjfH/ . But now I am trying to understand how I can control the fill so that it will be in the area that represents the difference between the two lines. In the example, economy should have a fill between 2 and 3, education should have a fill between 1.5 and 3 etc.

Comment: For what you're trying to do, it may actually be easier to use an area generator.